# Probability of getting a parking ticket ceteris paribus

Tags: probability, economics

"Suppose you have an opportunity to buy a ticket to a concert that includes your favorite band/performer. You have a choice about how much to pay for the ticket. You have 200 dollars in your wallet. A ticket normally costs 100. Ticketmeister has tickets for sale at a discounted rate of 56 dollars for the same quality seats. HOWEVER, in order to purchase the last discounted ticket, you will have to park illegally. The cost of a parking ticket is $80.

Ceteris paribus, if you only care about saving money on the cost of the concert ticket, you should park illegally only if the probability of getting caught is below ____%. (Fill in the blank)"

I need to know what the probability of getting caught as a function of the concert ticket price, but I have absolutely no idea where to start with this problem!

Comment: To save money, you want to spend less than $\$100$.  Therefore, you want the expected cost of the parking ticket to be less than $\$100 - \$56 = \$44$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I guess I still don't know where the probability of getting caught would come into play :/

Comment: The "expected cost of the parking ticket" is the cost of the parking ticket, $80, **times** the probability of getting caught.  I don't suppose you want to discuss the *morality* of breaking the law given a chance that you won't get caught.

Comment: I've fixed it, but if you don't know how to spell "ceteris paribus" why not just say it in English: "all things being equal"?

Comment: @RobArthan Please note the quotations and direct that question to my teacher, thanks.

Comment: OK Anne, it's not your fault. Over to your teacher .... Does he or she actually pronounce it as "ceretis"?

Comment: @RobArthan He's never actually said it, it was on the worksheet he assigned :/

So back to the question, would it be 80(x)=44, meaning 55%? It seems too easy hah..

Comment: New one on me, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus   I like the version caeteris paribus now that I see it, reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar

Comment: @Will Jagy For fun, I thought one moment that "Ceteris Partibus" was the name of the band.

Comment: @WillJagy "Ceteris paribus" in classical latin; in medieval latin we can find "coeteris" or "caeteris"

Comment: It _is_ as easy as you found it to be after you get past the use of Latin and realize it is a question of expected value.

Answer (score 2):

$C_p=56+80=136$ is the cost if caught.

$C_{1-p}=56+ 0=56$ is the cost if not.

The expected cost is then
$$\Bbb E(C)=pC_p+(1-p)C_{1-p}=136p+56(1-p)=80p+56$$
and we have
$$\Bbb E(C)=80p+56\le 100\quad\text{if}\quad p\le\frac{44}{80}=0.55=55\%$$

Comment: I have the same result-maybe with a slightly different approach. The expected cost if he/she parks illegally is $56+80p$ and the expected cost if he/she buys a normal ticket is just $100$.